# Display only sub order number that have MOrderNo

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 columns which are MOrderNum and SubOrderNum. MOrderNum is for Master Order No that created after approving Sub Order No. How to only display the MSubNum that have multiple SubOrderNum?

Example

| MOrderNum | SubOrderNum |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | A123-01 |
| A123 | A123-02 |
| M111 | B001 |
| M222 | C001 |

the data that should be displayed is

| MOrderNum | SubOrderNum |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | A123-01 |
| A123 | A123-02 |

Comment: `Where MOrderNum is not null` ?? OR `Where MOrderNum != ' '` ??

Comment: @Ullas, I've tried to put the where condition, but it still showing the value that is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 --it will check if MOrderNum exists in the counting list
SELECT MOrderNum, SubOrderNum
from tbl
WHERE MOrderNum in(
      --It will take all the MOrderNum with their count more than one
      SELECT MOrderNum FROM tbl
      GROUP BY MOrderNum
      HAVING COUNT(MOrderNum)>1
  )
 Order by MOrderNum
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8228f/2)

Comment: No Problem. Happy to help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this more efficiently with a window function**

```sql
SELECT MOrderNum, SubOrderNum
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MOrderNum)
    FROM tbl
) tbl
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work as well:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MOrderNum
    FROM [your table]    
    GROUP BY MOrderNum
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SubOrderNum) > 1  
    ) AS b 
INNER JOIN [your table] AS a              
ON a.MOrderNum = b.MOrderNum
ORDER BY a. MOrderNum
```